# Cell losing attributes in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view with cells showing state of device on the screen. The devices that are out of stock are grayed out by adjusting the alpha of the cell. But the moment I scroll on the screen or tap on any cell, the cells reload and lose the settings. Code here :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        self.allDevices = self.allDevices.sorted(by: {$0.givenName.lowercased() < $1.givenName.lowercased()})
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let deviceSKU = self.allDevices[indexPath.row].name
        let deviceName = self.allDevices[indexPath.row].givenName
        var alphaValue = 1.0
        var enableValue = true
        if self.allDevices[indexPath.row].connectFlag != nil {
            alphaValue = (self.allDevices[indexPath.row].connectFlag == "1") ? 1.0 : 0.2
            enableValue = (self.allDevices[indexPath.row].connectFlag == "1") ? true : false
        }

        if deviceSKU == "STS001" {
            let deviceImage = (self.allDevices[indexPath.row].state == true) ? UIImage(named: "socket-green.png") : UIImage(named: "socket-red.png")
            cell.configure(with: deviceImage!, name: deviceName, offline: alphaValue, enabled: enableValue)
        }
        if deviceSKU == "DWS01" {
            let deviceImage = (self.allDevices[indexPath.row].state == true) ? UIImage(named: "door-close2.png") : UIImage(named: "door-open2.png")
                    cell.configure(with: deviceImage!, name: deviceName, offline: alphaValue, enabled: enableValue)
            
        }
        
        if deviceSKU == "BWS01" {
            let deviceImage = (self.allDevices[indexPath.row].state == true) ? UIImage(named: "wallsocket-on.png") : UIImage(named: "wallsocket-off.png")
            cell.configure(with: deviceImage!, name: deviceName, offline: alphaValue, enabled: enableValue)
            
        }
        
        if deviceSKU == "5CHN" {
            let deviceImage = UIImage(named: "5Channel.png")
            cell.configure(with: deviceImage!, name: deviceName, offline: alphaValue, enabled: enableValue)
            
        }

    }
    
        return cell
    
 }
```

The cell.configure function in the UICollectionViewCell file :

```
public func configure(with image: UIImage, name: String, offline : CGFloat, enabled : Bool){
    deviceImage.image = image
    deviceName.text = name
    self.alpha = offline
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = enabled
}
```

I am also marking cell.userInteractionEnabled as false but this is retained but the cell.alpha setting is being lost. The cells that are greyed out initially when the data is loaded, go back to being at normal visibility whenever I click on any cell on the screen which allows userinterction or I scroll and these particular cells are off the visible area which is when they start reloading with alpha = 1.

Comment: Why do you have an async dispatch in your `cellForItem`? Start by getting rid of that. It is also inefficient to keep sorting `self.allDevices` and you should use `indexPath.item` for a collection view

Comment: Thanks, I did all that but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Since cells get reused you must set the state for all possible cases. You are not resetting the state in the case where all of the `if` statements are false.

The best approach is to override the `prepareForReuse()` function in your custom cell class.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    deviceImage.image = nil
    deviceName.text = ""
    self.alpha = 1
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true    
}
```

Adjust the code as needed. I based those lines on what you were doing in your `configure` method.

This ensures each cell gets reset to a fresh state after being dequeued in `cellForItemAt`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but nothing changes. I set the alpha to 0.5 and userInteractionEnabled = false for all the cells, but still the same condition as before. 

Here is a GIF showing the issue : https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExZjM1MWQyZWQ3NTQxNzk3Y2Q5MWIxNTVjYTY0NzE0YzEzYWU4ZTIxZSZjdD1n/MZrlNB4ciOoHNre2r6/giphy.gif

At the start the inactive devices are graded out, but when I scroll, one cell becomes visible again, then when I click on the active device,all the grayed out cell become visible. Note that even though they become visible bt the userInteraction remains disabled

Comment: Also make sure you remove the use of `DispatchQueue.main.async` from `cellForItemAt` and don't sort the data in `cellForItemAt`. The data should only be sorted once, not for every cell request.

Comment: Yes I have removed both, the dispatch queue and the sorting. The gif is after doing all that, there doesn't seem to be any change in the behaviour.